# Visual Studio Online Include Custom Assemblies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, tfs, azure-devops

Here's the scenario:

- In Visual Studio Online
- Single *Project Collection* - *DefaultCollection*
- 5 Different Solutions
- 1 Solution has a dependency on the other 4
- Trying to use build process template *TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml* in order to perform an automatic deployment from VSO to Azure Web Application
- Needing the first 4 solutions to build so that the 5th solution will build, however, it cannot find the dependencies no matter what I try.

Here's what I've attempted thus far...

**First Attempt**

1. Added the 4 additional source control paths to the "Source Settings"
2. Added the 4 additional solutions (in order) to the Process -> Build - Projects
3. This is the ONLY way the solution will build, HOWEVER, Continuous Deployment is skipped due to multiple solutions being built.

**Second Attempt**

1. Compiled the first 4 and copied them to the Drop folder
2. Set the additional source control path to the Drop folder
3. 5th Solution build fails because it cannot find references

**Third Attempt**

1. Compiled the first 4 and copied them to the Drop folder
2. Set the include folder on the build controller to the Drop folder
3. 5th Solution build fails because it cannot find references

**Fourth Attempt**

1. Compiled the first 4 and copied them to the Drop folder
2. Downloaded the contents of the Drop folder and checked the contents into a subdirectory of the BuildProcessTemplates folder in the 5th project.
3. Set the include folder on the build controller to the checked-in folder
4. 5th Solution build fails because it cannot find references

Any thoughts? I'm at a loss.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `cannot find references` ? Is it the library/assembly references or project references for that solution ?

Comment: The project in the 5 solution cannot find the library/assembly references of the other 4 compiled solutions (i.e. the .dll's).  Therefore, the 5th solution will not build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution that you take a dependant on should publish it's output as a Nuget package to a local repository. Your other solutions can then take a dependency on that package.

You can then control the version of the dependency.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for the pointer.  Upon your wisdom, that's essentially what I did. 1) Created a MyGet.org account 2) Added my dependencies as nuget packages to MyGet.org 3) Added my dependencies to the 5th solution as nuget packages 4) Enabled nuget download on the solution 5) Added the public feed url to the Nuget.Targets file.  Now upon compile, MSBuild finds the packages without a problem.  Thanks again!

Comment: You can have the builds for the other solutions publish their output to MyGet automatically.